# Storing multiple times/data in a MySQL databse

Tags: mysql, database

I'm looking at storing fight punch data in my MySQL database. Here's what I would need to store for each:

Time in the round of the punch
round of punch, 
type of punch (left hook, right hook, uppercut, ~6 variants)
landed/not landed

Now if I store a DB row for each punch and each fighter, the table would get huge pretty quick with each fight. Is there a way to make this smaller and more efficient? JSON/Serialised data in a field maybe, then just have a row for a single round or each round and fighter? This way I'd only have a 12/24 records per fight max for a 12 round fight.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you think already on the structure of the tables? If you divide the structure in multiple tables 6 - 8, I think it will not be a problem having a table with 50 - 70 registers per round (thinking that the fighter hits this amount of times). Another way is like you says, a row for each round, and making only a column of strings or varchars divided by comas (lh,lh,rh,u, etc) lh= left hook, rh = right hook, u = uppercut

Comment: If you want to analyse the data from within MySQL then normalisation is your only option.

Comment: json/serialised data in a column? no. in the recent mayweather/pacquiao fight, there were 865 punches thrown in total. at that rate, it would take over 23,000 fights to hit 20,000,000 rows, which even then I wouldn't say is a 'huge' table. Get your normalisation and indexes right, and your problem is 99% solved.